# Python os.getenv returning None, missing var on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, batch-file, windows-10

( >= Python 3.4 )

With `os.getenv()`, i am not able to retrieve some env vars, like `%DATE%` or `%TIME%`,

ex:

```
print(os.getenv('computername'))  # works
print(os.getenv('date'))  # not working, returning None
print(os.getenv('time'))  # not working, returning None
```

So i checked the list of var env python can detect by this:
`[print(var) for var in os.environ]`
It result a list of lot of env, but missing `date`, and `time`, at least.
A strange thing is the last item of the list is a list of `None` objects, probably the missing var env, but only appearing when using the interactive console.. and thus not really in the list.. or maybe some artifacts of the print function used in the interactive console?

Try

```
import os
varenv = [var for var in os.environ]
[print(var) for var in varenv]`
```

with the interactive console from the command line

Finally, when your are in windows cmd, `echo %date% %computername%` works great, with no different processing between these var.

I presume it's maybe related with unicode, but havent found any answers yet in my researches: Why `%DATE%` or `%TIME%` not working while `%computername%` just fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` are not environment variables.

See this Microsoft documentation [User Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/bb776899(v=vs.85).aspx#) to see the list of environment variables of your system.

Comment: `DATE` and `TIME` are fake environment variables available in the cmd.exe shell, along with `CD`, `RANDOM`, and `ERRORLEVEL`. The Windows API also has a couple of virtual variables for the current directory (`__CD__`) and application directory (`__APPDIR__`) as well as 'hidden' environment variables that start with `=`, such as the ones for the working directory on each drive such as `=D:` for the D: drive. These are only accessible by calling `GetEnvironmentVariable` directly.

Comment: It seems %DATE% and %TIME% are [Dynamic environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). But i can't find a nice way to retrieve these var in python.

Comment: @GuillaumeLebreton, they're just fake variables in cmd.exe. If you need them for some reason, use `subprocess.check_output('cmd /u /c "echo %{}%"'.format(name)).decode('utf-16le').rstrip()`, for a given `name` such as `"DATE"`. We need to use UTF-16 to be sure there's no mojibake or best-fit encoding.